# Как скрыть панель при действии с картой UWP C#

Tags: c#, uwp, карты, windows-10-mobile

Есть карта MapControl, на которой находятся элементы (MapIcon). При клике на любой из элементов появляется панель  ButtonPanel и остаётся видимой всё время, меняется только её содержание, в зависимости от дальнейших действий с MapIcon'ами.

```
List<item> items = new List<item>();
item SelectedItem = null;

    private void MyMap_MapElementClick(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapControl sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapElementClickEventArgs args)
{       

    MapIcon myClickedIcon = args.MapElements.FirstOrDefault(x => x is MapIcon) as MapIcon;

    foreach (MapIcon element in MyMap.MapElements)
    {
        if (element == myClickedIcon)
        {
            SelectedItem = Items.ElementAt(MyMap.MapElements.IndexOf(element));
            textBlock1.Text = Item.number +", " + Item.status;
            return;                 
        }                
        ButtonPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Как заставить эту панель ButtonPanel исчезать, если, например, просто просматриваешь карту, а при действии с MapIcon, чтобы она снова становилась Visible.